# Проблема с кодировкой в Debian Squeeze v.6.0.4 amd64

Tags: кодировка, debian, linux

При переходе с Шindows на Debian поместил инфу в zip-архив, с помощью "Отправить -> Сжатая zip-папка", и записал на болванку. Открываю диск с архивом уже на Debian, но вместо названия знаки вопроса(каюсь, нельзя было название кириллицей давать). Как решить сию проблему? Прошу прощения, если не туда написал.

Comment: sudo dpkg-reconfigure locales,выбирете и установите нужную кодировку!

Comment: Проблема усложняется. С помощью Midnight Commander'a я смог открыть архивы, все файлы в них тоже с именами в стиле "??????????"

Comment: Я закрываю вопрос, так как нашел другой выход из проблемы.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

нужно менять опции монтирования: http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mountcodepage и iocharset для Вас.К сожалению точные опции подсказать сходу не могу. скорее всего -o iocharset=utf8,codepage=cp1251,guest

Answer (score 0):

Каким архиватором открываете? можно попробовать установить чисто unrar, несколько раз удавалось открыть архивы с русскими названиями. Он их вроде даже понимает. Если не поможет, попробуйте поставить 7-zip, тоже достаточно умная прога.Если вдруг решите ставить unrar, то сначала надо удалить rar, если таковой установлен.